# No matching index found even Google Cloud show them

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT google_uid FROM User WHERE api_key = @api_key
```

But I get the error:

> no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: User\n
>   properties:\n - name: api_key\n - name: google_uid\n

Here is the index configuration from Google:
[image]

I uploaded it yesterday, so I am sure Google have had time to update it on their side.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: So far I have been testing the Data in my Datastore I've seen everything working correct.

Can you make sure the specific value "@api_key" does exist in your database?

Comment: exists for sure

Answer (score 0):

The properties in the index are ordered.  So you have an index of (google_uid, api_key), but you don't have an index of (api_key, google_uid).  This query requires a composite index of (api_key, google_uid) .

You can see this if you run the query`SELECT data_clicked from User where api_key = @api_key` .  That will work since  you have an index where api_key is the first property.